# Will a login type app be rejected or not in AppStore?

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

Respected Everybody,

I have the application that start from the login credential(userid and password) that can be get from the website only.

After login user can access all the functionality otherwise not. So here the question is :

Is this type of application is rejected by the appstore or not and if rejected then what all are the solutions or steps that may require to implement from my side ?

Or is there any way then i will provide the dummy userid and password to the appstore,and if there exists then where to give that userid & password for the testing purpuse to the apple team ?

Please provide me the proper solution so that i can upload my application on the appstore its urgent so provide as soon as possible.

Comment: Want a place where you could ask such questions without being offtopic? Commit to our [App Stores site Proposal at area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores?referrer=jcBbxTFsYbhSPTdluUKgFA2)! Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When you submit your app to the app store on itunesconnect.apple.com there is a section where you can enter Review Notes.  These are meant as notes intended for the Apple employee who will review your app.  If your app requires the user to login you can enter a test username and password for the reviewer to use in this section.  Your app will not be rejected for having a login screen as long as you provide a valid username & password to the reviewer.